# This model is too slow. I'm looking for a good, fast-enough, out-of-the-box, pre-trained image classifier. Any tip?

Tags: python, image-classification, performance, pretraining

I have been using this on a laptop without a GPU: https://github.com/pharmapsychotic/clip-interrogator

Currently it takes about 10s to classify a single image on my own computer.

I use `config.apply_low_vram_defaults()` and `ci.interrogate_fast()`

Are there other faster, lighter, out-the-box, pre-trained image classifiers?

I'm not really looking for very high quality image classification, but I'd rather have some decent speed instead. I know it might be a difficult compromise, but I'm willing to try it.

Am I missing a configuration with that tool? I've also reduced chunk_size to 256, without much effect.

```
ci = None
cfg = None
from PIL import Image

def init_clip():
    global ci
    global cfg

    from clip_interrogator import Config, Interrogator
    # image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')

    cfg = Config(
        clip_model_name="ViT-L-14/openai",
        chunk_size = 256,
        )
    cfg.apply_low_vram_defaults()
    ci = Interrogator(cfg)
    print("finished initing clip")
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import Response
import flask
import dataset


######### dataset #########
imgdescr = None
imgdb = None

def init_dts():
    global imgdb
    global imgdescr
    imgdb = dataset.connect('sqlite:///imgdb.nogit.db')
    imgdescr = imgdb['imgdescr']

def insert_descr(filename, text):
    global imgdescr
    imgdescr.insert(dict(filename=filename,text=text))

def init():
    init_dts()
    init_clip()

# flask http callbacks
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return open('img_classifier.html', encoding='utf8').read()

@app.route("/single", methods = ['POST'])
def single():
    global ci

    if request.method == 'POST':
        single_img = request.data.decode('utf-8')

        image_obj = Image.open(single_img).convert('RGB')
        print(image_obj.size)
        text_result = ci.interrogate_fast(image_obj)
        insert_descr(single_img, text_result)

        return f'{single_img}\n\n{text_result}'

@app.route("/get_json", methods = ['POST'])
def get_json():
    global ci
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_path = request.data.decode('utf-8')
        return f'you sent {json_path}'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002)
```

Comment: Have you tried switching to a different (lighter) CLIP model (e.g. ViT Base instead of ViT Large)?

Comment: Have you looked at hugging face?

Comment: @Oxbowerce where is the list of model's names?

Comment: @CarlosMougan hugginface also points to this same repo, what are refererring to?

Comment: The repository uses the `open_clip` package to load the CLIP model, which has a list of models on [the repository read me](https://github.com/mlfoundations/open_clip).

Comment: vit 16 is long to load especially at the flavors stage...

Comment: @Oxbowerce vit32 is also very slow to advance the flavor stage...

Comment: @jokoon I think your laptop is too slow for DL especially without a GPU. Try a cloud service or upgrade to a new one.

Comment: So deep learning is slow even outside of the learning process.